# Connection pooling + Impersonating queries

Tags: spring-security, connection-pooling, ibm-midrange, jt400, jtopen

I'm working on a spring(IoC/ MVC/ Security)/ JTOpen project backed up by DB2 over IBM System i (AS/400). For reasons I won't be able to discuss here, every user of the application was given an account on the IBM i (i5/OS) operating system so that his transactions get logged against his identity in the Journal (DB2 log files). In order to achieve that we have been establishing a connection once someone logs into the system using his credentials and accordingly getting his transactions against his name in the Journal.

**Problem:** 
Recently, we have been investigating on getting a connection pool in place instead of the status quo of connection per session. If the pool establishes these connections once the application starts using a generic i5/OS account, say: SystemAccount, then a user logs in a requests one of these connections, is there any way to execute transactions under the identity of the user although it was established using the generic system account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [com.ibm.as400.security.auth](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/security/auth/package-summary.html) package provides classes that allow user profile swapping using IBM i profile token and credential classes when using the [AS400](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/as400obj.htm) connection class.

If you are using [JDBC](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/jdbc2.htm) you can call the [Security-related APIs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/apis/sec1.htm) to adopt profiles on the connection.

- [Get Profile Handle](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/apis/QSYGETPH.htm) (QSYGETPH) validates a user ID and password, and creates an encrypted abbreviation called a profile handle for that user profile.
- [Set Profile Handle](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/apis/QWTSETP.htm) (QWTSETP) switches the job to run under a new profile.
- [Generate Profile Token](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/apis/qsygenpt.htm) (QSYGENPT) verifies that the caller has authority to generate a profile token for the requested profile and then generates a profile token.
- [Set To Profile Token](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/apis/qsysetpt.htm) (QSYSETPT) validates the profile token and changes the current thread to run under the user and group profiles represented by the profile token.

Comment: Tried using `swap()` in `com.ibm.as400.security.auth.AS400Credential` class which is supposed to

>swap the current thread identity based on this credential

It throws back an exception with the following message: "swap() is supported only when running natively on IBM i". Same message is used as a note in the [JavaDoc of the swap function](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/index.html?com/ibm/as400/security/auth/AS400Credential.html). Does that mean that the swap command has to come from a program hosted on the AS/400, or that my whole application has to be hosted locally on the AS/400?

Comment: @Eyad That may be a limitation of the auth classes.  I have used the API methods to adopt profiles over remote connections.

Comment: Seems like it. The API methods worked like a charm. So I guess the only option left is to write a program to switch the identity and call it from my application which doesn't really feel right (from a security point of view).

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the transactions are actually being improperly logged? I wouldn't expect them to be.